# is the Riemann Mapping Theorem true on the extended plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

suppose we define a simply connected domain for the extended complex plane as this:

> Let G be a domain in the extended complex plane, i.e., the image under
>   stereographic projection of an open connected set on the Riemann
>   Sphere. Then G is said to be **simply connected** if whenever G
>   contains a closed Jordan curve $\gamma$, G also contains either its
>   interior $I(\gamma)$ or its exterior $E(\gamma)$.

With this definition I am trying to generalizethe Riemann Mapping Theorem but I am not sure how. So far I got this:

> Any simply connected domain G in the extended complex plane other than
>   the whole extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cup\infty$ or the finite
>   complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is a conformal image of the open unit disk.

I know G can't be the finite complex plane or the extended complex plane because of the Liouville's theorem and [it's generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces) to compact Riemann surfaces.

My question is: is this generalization right? And if so, how would I prove it? Maybe using the stereographic projection and composing with the map from the original theorem?

Comment: After a Möbius transformation your $G$ is a domain $\subset \Bbb{C}$ so that's the usual Riemann mapping